# Sending Protobuf message to Web API Failing

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api2, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using Microsoft Web API 2 and Protobuf-net to serialize my data. Everything is working perfectly, except when I want to send binary data to the Web API controller. I end up getting a 500 error.

Is this currently possible or is this restricted to serialization only? To verify my response was correct, I used ProtobufJS and it decoded it correctly. To pinpoint my issue, I excluded it and directly sent my response as soon as I got it. Any help getting set up would be greatly appreciated.

Web API Controller

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public User Get()
    {
        var user = new User{ Id = "ABC1", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
        return user;
    }

    // GET api/user/
    public void Post(User user)
    {
        var type = "POST";
    }
}
```

Model

```
[ProtoContract]
public class User
{

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>

    var get = new XMLHttpRequest();
    get.open("GET", "api/user", true);
    get.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    get.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/x-protobuf");

    get.onload = function (event) {

        var arrayBuffer = get.response;

        var post = new XMLHttpRequest();
        post.open("POST", "api/user", true);
        post.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/x-protobuf");
        post.overrideMimeType("application/x-protobuf");

        post.send(arrayBuffer);

    }

    get.send(null);

</script>
```